# How long can I stay in Canada?

Tags: canada, residence-cards

I am an Irish citizen living in the USA with a permanent resident card. I own a house in Canada.

How long can I stay in Canada at one time before returning to USA?

And if I return to USA how soon can I turn around and go back to Canada, and for how long can I stay?

Comment: This looks like an expats question more than a TSE, as it is about long times and regular returns.

Comment: Having a house in Canada (and none in USA) might look to official authorities like you do not intent to be permanent resident of USA. That might be a problem. In which country you want to be permanent resident?

Answer (score 1):

Well as an Irish citizen, at least, [you don't need a visa](http://www.immigration.ca/canada-visit-tourist-visa/), but still need the ETA (do it online to prevent delays).

Most visitors are admitted for [six months](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16), unless otherwise specified by the Border Officer at time of entry.

How long before your next trip? Depends on the border officer's view of your plans. Having a house will raise flags. He'll wonder if you're trying to 'live' in Canada without really living there (travelling in and out repeatedly).  So you may be required to provide evidence that you live in the US - bank accounts, utilities bill, contract of employment etc, and show the date you anticipate leaving Canada, possibly even evidence of your return ticket.

(sources include those linked, and my personal experience after living there for a year, and several other trips)

Comment: US permanent residents are visa exempt in Canada regardless of their nationality.

Comment: it doesn't change anything, does it?  It just means in this case that she has two reasons for the exemption rather than one.